# jQuery javascript datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the datetimepicker from this site:
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

It works nice, but not perfect. I need to make the "Today" button set the field to "2010-11-21 23:24" instead of "2010-11-21". Important is, that when I don't use the timepicker (because it's the jQuery UI datepicker extension), it just gives "2010-11-21". The Problem is, i'm not that into javascript. Could anybody help me with this one?

The code can be found here:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: Crikey. I hit up the post as I'm after a time selector - not sure that the one featured actually makes things any easier than a drop-down or plain text field!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom format

```
$('#selector').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
});
```

Internally the plugin will already set the date & time to the current date & time. You dont have to write any code for this. It's just a matter of formatting the result...

Comment: jQuery('.datetime').datetimepicker({showSecond: false,timeFormat: 'hh:mm',dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}); Does not work